# How to let the html image move to a certain place?

Tags: javascript, html

my image cannot to move to the place that I set.

this is some code that i found in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REvbEZ it not working when i try to apply into my code.
I have try to change some movement but its does not working at all.

```
$('.add-to-cart').on('click', function () {
        var cart = $('.shopping-cart');
        var imgtodrag = $(this).parent('.item').find("img").eq(0);
        if (imgtodrag) {
            var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                .offset({
                top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                left: imgtodrag.offset().left
            })
                .css({
                'opacity': '0.5',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'height': '150px',
                    'width': '150px',
                    'z-index': '100'
            })
                .appendTo($('body'))
                .animate({
                'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                    'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
                    'width': 75,
                    'height': 75
            }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');
    });
```

Let the product image move to the cart image after i press the add to cart button. 
This is for the user to know the product is successfully added to the cart.

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Comment: you can use    transition and set value which you want to change depending on direction you want to move your image.

Comment: Code is for understanding and rewritting, not copy pasting. Begin there, ask specific questions after

Comment: Just use **margin**